# Ruby - How to check only the first return value of a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Right now I have this Ruby method that returns 3 different numbers:

```
# Find integers s and t such that gcd(a,b) = s*a + t*b
# pre: a,b >= 0
# post: return gcd(a,b), s, t
def egcd(a, b)
  # let A, B = a, b
  s, t, u, v = 1, 0, 0, 1
  while 0 < b
    # loop invariant: a = sA + tB and b = uA + vB and gcd(a,b) = gcd(A,B)
    q = a / b
    a, b, s, t, u, v = b, (a%b), u, v, (s-u*q), (t-v*q)
  end
  [a, s, t]
end
```

I want to only check the first return value, a.

```
if egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128) != 1
```

So this statement here does not work since it's returning 3 values, I just want to check if the first value is != 1. I'm fairly new to Ruby, does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: your method returns just _one_ value – an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the first value of an array can be done in a few ways:

```
if egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128).first != 1
```

or

```
if egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128)[0] != 1
```

If you're only using the first value, I'd suggest re-writing your program to be a little more intuitive. I'd also consider re-writing this piece of code entirely as it doesn't read nicely at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since your return value is an array, check to see if the first value of the array is not 1.

`if egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128).first != 1`

or

`unless egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128).first == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

`if egcd(ARGV[3].to_i, 128)[0] != 1`

...since the return is actually an array.